# How to make a custom request in zend framework

Tags: zend-framework

i wanna use zend  framework for a series sites with same features but different style and language

the url would be like this

```
http://www.<style>.com/<language>/<controller>/<action>
```

how do i add plugins into zend framework to make it work

i can modify

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
```

to realize the language feature, but it broke the urls in views.
should i create a url helper for views?

and set

```
$view->setScriptPath($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])
```

in controller to realize the style feature
but it's really not look grace

i wish a can get a request

```
$request->getParams()
```

will return

```
array(
    'controller'=> <controller>,
    'action'=><action>,
    'module'=><module>,
    'language'=><language>,
    'style'=><style>
)
```

what i should do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create routes for your applications. See http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.router.html . You can modify your routes to include the language.

Comment: this thread is more helpful, [how to create customized default route](http://zend-framework-community.634137.n4.nabble.com/Working-with-multilanguage-routers-td662627.html)